# Laravel 5 get URI causing NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

If I am catching a NotFoundHttpException in the Exceptions/Handler.php file in Laravel 5, how can I log the URI causing the exception?

I have seen all kinds of answers about setting up the routes file correctly (did that) but I can't seem to see how I can log the offending URI.

Any ideas?

Comment: Show the code that is catching the `NotFoundHttpException`; there's likely a `request` object available at that point, you could simply `\Log::info($request);` or `\Log::info(request());` at that point to save it to your Laravel log. Might even be able to narrow it down with a specific method on the request object, like `\Log::info(request()->getUrl());` (don't recall the exact method off the top of my head)

Comment: If you want the query string use `$request->fullUrl()`, if not, use `$request->url()`. As @TimLewis suggested, depending on your context, you can use the `request()` helper too.